# Trouble with codesigning NW.js app for MacOS

Tags: code-signing, nw.js

NWJS Version : 0.28.0

Operating System : MacOS 10.13.3

Here is a fragment of bash script that I use for codesign:

```
export IDENTITY=YFXXXXXXXX
export PARENT_PLIST=./certs/parent.plist
export CHILD_PLIST=./certs/child.plist

codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $helpersPath/nwjs\ Helper.app
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $helpersPath/nwjs\ Framework.framework/Versions/A/Resources/app_mode_loader.app
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $helpersPath/nwjs\ Framework.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/AlertNotificationService.xpc
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $helpersPath/nwjs\ Framework.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/crashpad_handler
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $helpersPath/nwjs\ Framework.framework/Versions/A/nwjs\ Framework
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $helpersPath/nwjs\ Framework.framework/libnode.dylib
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $helpersPath/libffmpeg.dylib
codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $PARENT_PLIST $APP_PATH

chmod -R 777 $APP_PATH

cd $APP_DIR && productbuild --component "$APP_NAME.app" /Applications --sign $IDENTITY "$APP_NAME.pkg"
```

I signed everything that Application Loader and ITunesConnect asked for. I had a lot of issues before while uploading a package. It all has been solved by codesigning everything. Now the package can be uploaded. However, I can't run .app after codesign. Before codesign it works good.

Here is also child and parent plists.
Child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Edit:**

Also extracted from system.log:

```
Feb 6 12:10:43 MacBook-Air-Mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.nwjs Helper.779): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Users/mac/Desktop/lal/Trader.app/Contents/Versions/64.0.3282.119/nwjs Framework.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/AlertNotificationService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Users/mac/Desktop/lal/Trader.app/Contents/Versions/64.0.3282.119/nwjs Helper.app
```

Comment: Added more details.